# IKEA Poang install problem

Tags: repair, screws

Slats for the back got put on backwards.  Everything unscrewed except one screw which looks like it’s stuck spinning.  Any idea on how to get it out?[image]

Comment: The vertical piece has round marks around that bolt as though a socket was on there and spun, but I can't fathom how someone may have used a socket to try to drive this bolt in. I've got hex keys, and I've got hex drivers (in 3/8" and 1/2" driver size), but none of them would make marks like that. Where did that circular damage come from?

Comment: Can you include photos of your instructions or a link to the document?  I do not see anything in [these Poang instructions](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/assembly_instructions/poang-rocking-chair-frame__AA-370711-9_pub.pdf)  that looks like your photo.  The chair back slats are pre-assembled.  Just guessing though ... is there a tee nut on the back of that bolt that needs to be held with a second allen wrench?  What does it screw into?

Comment: Take it back to Ikea and ask them to help, they seem to have good customer support.

Answer (score 1):

Three-handed job…
Push the tenon in to release pressure on the joint.
Simultaneously get a screwdriver, steel rule etc under the bolt head & lever towards you as you unscrew.

[image]

Comment: Would add on how to repair the hole to your answer.   I hate three-handed jobs.

Comment: It's going to depend on what you find when the bolt comes out. Sometimes they're just glorified wood screws, sometimes with captive brass inserts that may become 'un-captive', or at worst, solidly cross-threaded & therefore you'd have to sacrifice it completely. At work we used to just drill or smash those out [usually from metal constructions] & either rebuild with the next size up or discard the entire unit.

Comment: I don't understand the release pressure part.  I already tried sticking a screwdriver under the head and it didn't help.  Keeps spinning